# Is possible to change the motherboard of a HP Touchsmart 1080la tablet pc?

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard

I want to upgrade a HP Touchsmart 1080la tablet pc, with a faster processor and better memory. Is this possible? Which hardware is compatible?

I've performed an Internet search about this, but I haven't found a list of compatible motherboards to perform an upgrade.

Comment: This entirely depends on the exact CPU you have. Your memory likely can be upgraded the service manual for the device will indicate if you can upgrade the memory.  If I found the correct model, the CPU cannot be upgrade, the memory can go up to 4GB.

Comment: The CPU is a 2Ghz Core 2 Duo. My main interest is changing the motherboard, but I haven't found a compatibility list that helps in this case.

Comment: You won't be able to replace the motherboard with anything except a replacement of the same motherboard. Due to the age of the hardware ( 6 years ) you would pay more for the replacement hardware then the entire system is worth.  **The CPU cannot be replaced by an end user**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as CPU, it's very unlikely.  It is extremely rare when a tablet, notebook or laptop PC can have it's CPU upgraded without replacing the entire motherboard.  The majority of the time in these devices, the CPU is soldered to the motherboard and not in a removable socket like most desktop PCs.  And that's only if you can find one that fits the same format and shell.  In your case, it's a custom HP motherboard and depending on the exact variant of model you bought, you may find HP offering a motherboard with a faster CPU, but it's pretty much guaranteed it will be cheaper for you to just buy a new tablet in that case.

It's far more likely that the memory can be upgraded.  In your case, the answer is yes, but it depends on what you already have installed.  If you already have the largest amount of memory the device supports (8 GB in your case in two 4 GB SODIMMS), then you can go no further.  If you don't have 8 GB of memory, that's about your only upgrade path with this device.

[Your device's hardware manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c02060084.pdf).